# How to save hd image in from alasset to documents folder in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiimage, save

Trying to save ultra hd image in documents directory from gallery. My app is crashing due to memory pressure. How to save image directly from alasset to documents folder without taking into uiimage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have problems with memory I will suggest you to read this [How can I release memory of UIImages no longer used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22584478/how-can-i-release-memory-of-uiimages-no-longer-used/22584639#22584639)  first.

If you will decide that you still need copying without UIImage usage you can try following

```
ALAsset *result; // do not forget to initialize it
ALAssetRepresentation *rawImage = [result defaultRepresentation];

uint8_t *buffer = malloc( rawImage.size );
[rawImage getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0 length:rawImage.size error:NULL];
NSData *d = [NSData dataWithBytes:buffer length:rawImage.size];
[d writeToFile:@"your_file_path_here" atomically:YES];
free(buffer);
```

UPDATE:

Following code could be more efficient

```
long long sizeOfRawDataInBytes = rawImage.size;
NSMutableData* rawData = [[NSMutableData alloc]initWithCapacity:sizeOfRawDataInBytes];
void* bufferPointer = [rawData mutableBytes];
NSError* error=nil;
[rawImage getBytes:bufferPointer fromOffset:0 length:sizeOfRawDataInBytes error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Getting bytes failed with error: %@",error);
}
else {
    [rawData writeToFile: @"your_file_path_here" atomically:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the post it is helpfull for me...My memory usage is decrease.

Comment: Any idea for to store the Array of UIImage ?

Comment: @DivyeshDobariya Do the same several times.

Comment: When i save uiimage it gives error in the line    uint8_t *buffer = malloc( rawImage.size ); and   [rawImage getBytes:bufferPointer fromOffset:0 length:sizeOfRawDataInBytes error:&error];